# Can excess of logging contribute to high CPU utilization in apache tomcat

Tags: java, groovy, cpu

We are using Groovy, Grill, web socket and REST API in our application. Our production server shows high CPU as soon as there are 10+ users simultaneously accessing the app. On checking the server health I can see some logging activity showing high CPU (screenshot attached). I wanted to know if excess of logging contributes to high CPU utilization. Definitely there could be more other reasons for high CPU.

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you're asking here. Could excess logging result in a high CPU load? Yes, that's possible, although it's more likely to result in excess IO operations which curb CPU load. Is it the cause of the high CPU load that you're experiencing in your screenshot? There's no way to tell. It's possible, but there are a gazillion other possible reasons, such as having a high usage of the application.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks for your reply. Yes, I was looking for if excess of logging contributes to high CPU. Also is there any way/tool to find out the reason for the high CPU.

Comment: Use VisualVm for profiling. The reference to logging is just a parameter to the JVM, probably not related to the high CPU usage at all.

Comment: Wouldn't that be easily testable by just disabling all logging and measure again if you can't profile it?  E.g. stresstest a similar setup with ab/siege/gatling/...

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack thanks, VisualVM did help with some new findings.

Comment: @cfrick, yes, commenting all excess of logging helped a bit also there was an issue of improper indexing to one of MySQL table.

Comment: So as seen so many times in the past, a missing index, the wrong data type or algorithm is the culprit -- and not the odd assumtion.  I'm glad that measuring and testing helped you finding the proper solution to the problem so we don't end up with another "answer" here too that others blindly cargo-cult.